# Regex to add character after decimal in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list of 500 files or so of messy data sets (.csv) that look like the following:

```
0.00, 0.53, 1.53, 0.00 0.52, 243.21 
... etc etc.
```

I would like:

```
0.00, 0.53, 1.53, 0.00, 0.52, 243.21
```

In perl (or bash), how would I match everything after a decimal, and, IF there is **whitespace** followed by another **number**, then I would insert a comma after the first number?

i.e. `0.00 0.52` into `0.00, 0.52`

I'm a beginner to perl and programming in general, so I'm not quite understanding how to use this correctly.
I found that the regex `[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?`should work for two decimal places, but what about more decimals? Is it simply `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+?)?`

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
for my $file (glob '*.csv') {
    open my $in, '<', $file;        
    my @lines;
    while (<$in>) {
        while(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/g){
            print ",";      # Am I overwritting my lines here?  
        }
        $line =~ s/,,/,/g; # Get rid of any double commas that appear now
    }
    close $in;
    open my $out, '>', $file;
    print $out $_ for @lines;
    close $out;
}
```

I think I am not matching/printing correctly -- any help is appreciated, including more elegant solutions.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for lazy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    print join ( ", ", m/([\d\.]+)/g ); 
}

__DATA__
0.00, 0.53, 1.53, 0.00 0.52, 243.21
```

Output:

```
0.00, 0.53, 1.53, 0.00, 0.52, 243.21
```

This works by:

- repeat matching "digits and dots" into an array
- then prints that with comma separation. `join` doesn't insert a
  trailing delimiter.

So to take your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $file (glob '*.csv') {
    open my $in, '<', $file or die $!;
    open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die $!; 

    while (<$in>) {
        print {$out} join ( ", ", m/([\d\.]+)/g ); 
    }
}
```

This works because each iteration of the `while` loop automagically sets the implicit variable `$_` to "the current line". `m` and `s` regular expressions (along with a bunch of other perl functions) act on `$_` by default.

So you could rewrite that as:

```
while ( my $line = <$in> ) {
    my @stuff = $line =~ m/([\d\.]+)/g;
    print {$out} join ( ",", @stuff );
}
```

Implicit variables are nice for some things, but be wary of them - only use them if they make code more clear.

To answer your inlined queries:

> ## Am I overwritting my lines here?

No - that `print ","` is writing to STDOUT. That's not changing your file at all. (But neither is it actually doing anything useful).

You would have to use `s` pattern to search/replace on `$_` - the current line - and then `push` that into `@lines`.

I think you're misunderstanding a couple of basic concepts here though:

- `@lines` is nothing to do with `$line`. You don't actually do anything to `@lines` so it'll be empty when you print it.
- Your `while` and `print` loop - doesn't do anything. The `m` regular expression *does* apply to `$_` which is set implicitly to "current line" by the while loop. But you do nothing to actually change this value.
- `$line =~` ... transforms `$line`. But `$line` doesn't exist, so nothing happens.

You really should be adding `use strict;` and `use warnings` to the start of your program, because you would be warned about these things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak perl, but in principle:

```
Search: (?<=\.\d\d)(?= \d)
Replace: ,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can install Tie::File you can do this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

for my $file (glob '*.csv') {
    tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $file or die $!;
        s/(\d)(\s+\d)/$1,$2/g foreach (@file);
    untie @file;
}
```

Note that this will modify the original files.
Tie::File reads the file into array and allows you to modify data.